# Comma separated results for SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table `location`, which contains the values `A1, A2, A3...` etc in the `id` column. I have another table `location_color` like this:

```
A1   blue
A1   red
A1   green
A2   yellow
A2   red
A3   blue
A3   red
.
.
```

Now I want to query so the result would be like this

```
blue,red,green
yellow,red
Blue, red
```

My query is

```
select location_color.color
from location_color
where location.id = location_color.location_id
```

but it's not working.

Comment: In MySQL you can use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: Which RDBMS (vendor and version)? The tag *sql* is not enough...

Comment: You did not include the `location` table. But why do you want to have that `where` clause when you are not using anything from the `location` table? Just leave that `where` out.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items (in a column), it will only cause you lots of trouble! (One value per column/row is the SQL way.)

Comment: @jarlh, I think the question shows that the data is already stored that way (one value per row)

Comment: use `string_agg()` in Postgres

Comment: This was just closed as duplicate for a SQL-Server specific older question. Without spedifying the actual RDBMS. Seems to be to fast, doesn't it? This is - for sure! - a duplicate, but might be bound to the wrong question. And furthermore: The linked question does not handle several leading "IDs", which adds quite an amount of complexity...

Comment: Tag the dbms used! (The answer will be product specific!!!)

Comment: As M Mahrous was back and did not state the actual DBMS I'll vote for closing now...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, here is what you can use:

```
SELECT location_id, stuff((
        select DISTINCT ',' + u.location_color
        from #temp u
        where u.location_id = t.location_id
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as location_color_csv
FROM #temp t
GROUP BY t.location_id
```